# Помогите понять клиент-сервер

Tags: java, клиент-сервер

Изучаю серверы, пока на простом уровне.
Задача такая: сервер загадывает число, клиент должен его угадать.
Есть такой код на сервере:

```
   public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

        ServerSocket serverSocket = new ServerSocket(8000);

        while(true) {

            Socket clientSocket = serverSocket.accept();
            OutputStreamWriter writer = new OutputStreamWriter(clientSocket.getOutputStream());
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(clientSocket.getInputStream()));

            writer.write("Try to guess a number from 0 to 10: ");
            writer.flush();

//            String request = reader.readLine();
//            int num = Integer.parseInt(request);
//            System.out.println(num);

            writer.close();
            clientSocket.close();
        }
    }
```

И такой на клиенте:

```
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        Socket clientSocket = new Socket("127.0.0.1", 8000);
        OutputStreamWriter writer = new OutputStreamWriter(clientSocket.getOutputStream());
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(clientSocket.getInputStream()));

        String response = reader.readLine();
        System.out.println(response);

        String request = scanner.nextLine();
        writer.write(request);
        writer.flush();
```

Я иду последовательно. Сначала создаются сокеты и ридеры/райтеры. Сервер отправляет клиенту сообщение - попробуй угадать число. Клиент выводит его в консоль, но (! вот тут проблема !) ровно до того момента, пока я не активирую те строки, что в коде выше закомментированы.
Этого я не понимаю. Ведь сервер сначала должен передать сообщение, а потом ждать ответа в строке String request = reader.readLine();, но он не передает сообщение.

Comment: Может я чего-то в веб не понимаю, но где у вас генерация числа? Какая у вас очередность работы клиент/сервер? Я вижу код так, что сервер отправляет сообщение неважно куда, Клиент читает сообщение не важно откуда и не важно, может оно равно нулю и... сразу входит в сканер, где ожидается ввод. Не так?

Comment: Пальцем в небо, но попробуйте добавить проверку в клиент, что `whlie(response!=null)` типо ждать ответа от сервера

Comment: Генерация числа в отдельно методе, он ниже, просто в данный код не подключен, я не стал сюда вбивать все, что есть)

Пошагово:
1) Создается серверСокет с портом 8000 на локалхосте
2) while true, чтобы сервер не отключался при завершении задачи, и ждал следуюущю задачу
3) Создается clietnSocket на стороне сервере с методом accept() - ожидает входящего подключения.

4) в клиенте создается сокет, который подключается к локалхосту по порту 8000
5) в клиенте также создаются сканер, ридер и райтер.

Comment: 6) как только создано подключение, сервер в строке writer.write() отправляет сообщение.
7) клиент через reader.readLine() его принимает.
------ и вот тут случается трабл. 
дальше клиент должен получить от человека число и отправить его серверу также через writer.write();
а сервер должен его, в свою очередь, принять с помощью reader.readLine().

Вот только если включить в сервере эту строку, то он не отправляет самый первый райтер, который должен был отправить при активации подключения.
При этом, если ридер в сервере не запускать, то райтер он прекрасно отправляет.

Comment: Dred, Ваш совет пр response != null сработал. Вот только я не могу понять, почему) То есть ему сначала было сказано выводить строку в любом случае, и он ее не выводил, но почему он стал ее выводить, если условие, что строка не пустая, true

Comment: Ну, судя моей логики, у вас клиент подключается и ... пропускает момент того, что серер отправляет какое-то сообщение, а точнее, он выводит `null` и, недожидаясь сразу доходит до строки `String request = scanner.nextLine();` которая ждет ввода  чего-либо.  Это то, как я вижу по коду. Чтобы точнее быть, вы можете через дебагер запустить всё и посмотреть как у вас и что проходит

Comment: Да, Вы совершенно правы оказались - он не дожидается. Поставил Thread.sleep на 50 миллисекунд в клиенте перед приемом сообщения от сервера - все работает. Спасибо Вам большое!)

Answer (score 0):

Добавьте ожидание того, чтобы клиент проверял наличие текста от сервера. Например, так

```
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    Socket clientSocket = new Socket("127.0.0.1", 8000);
    OutputStreamWriter writer = new OutputStreamWriter(clientSocket.getOutputStream());
    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(clientSocket.getInputStream()));

    String response = reader.readLine();

       while(response!=null) {

       System.out.println(response);

       String request = scanner.nextLine();
       writer.write(request);
       writer.flush();
      }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Дело в том что ваш клиент ожидает строку `reader.readLine()`, а сервер окончания строки не передает `writer.write("Try to guess a number from 0 to 10: ");`

Поправьте на `writer.write("Try to guess a number from 0 to 10: \n");` и должно заработать.